# How to see changed settings in IntelliJ Idea?

Tags: intellij-idea

Is it possible to see all the settings that you've changed (from the default) in IntelliJ Idea? In VSCode, you can just open the JSON user settings and see the options changed. Or you can open the UI settings and it'll indicate which ones have been changed with a blue bar.

I know that there is a reset settings button in IntelliJ but I'm looking for a settings diff or anything equivalent.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All the settings (actually settings are diffs from default) are stored in the [Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory)

If you are using settings sync (IDE version >= 2022.3), you can see the history of changes by opening [[Configuration directory](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/directories-used-by-the-ide-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs.html#config-directory)]/settingsSync folder as a project in IntelliJ IDEA. Here is what you'll get:

[image: IntelliJ IDEA settings change history]